# GetScreenRect_PosMode() and GetScreenRect_SizeMode() returns -2

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv, smart-tv-alliance

I'm trying to figure out how to do PiP. I followed this guide:

http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/tec00103/index.html

This line:

```
alert('POSMODE : ' + pluginWindow.GetScreenRect_PosMode() + ', SIZEMODE : ' + pluginWindow.GetScreenRect_SizeMode());
```

returns -2 for both, PosMode and SizeMode. It's a negative value, so something went apparently wrong, but I can't figure out what. What does it mean? There is nothing showing on the screen either.

Can somebody help me out with this or point out tutorials for making PiP app?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial seems outdated for 2011 and below TV models.
Try to visit this link, the reply has attached PIG sample apps and i think easier to learn from what already done.

http://samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/7e2b7fa90012098b?forumID=6edcb9318bf4438f

The newer SDK should be able to use [sf.service.PIG](http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00009/pig_show.html) object to do the work

Comment: Ok, it seems your example is indeed working. I find the Samsung reference a bit clumsy, I had no idea that I'm using outdated method.

Comment: They make big changes from 2011 to 2012 Platform and i think the backward-compatibility is not going smoothly